# database and raw files on an android device

Tags: android, database, file

I have a raw folder in res folder which contains a file. When I run my application on actual device, its not able to get that file. Same is the issue with database.

Do I need to add the file separately onto the device?

Where can I find the database created on my device.

Comment: You should post the logcat message if you are getting issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can  able to see your database in DDMS perspective.

Run your application.

**windows->open perspective->other-> DDMS**

at the right side .three tabs will be there .open File explorer you can find your running application there.just click that.you can find database folder under it.

Comment: hey... just to confirm you talking about device or eclipse? I can see it on eclipse on file explorer... but have no idea where is file explorer visible on actual device...

Comment: for device file explorer not possible in ddms perspective.

Comment: use emulator for view the db.